# How to keep Background Console on uninstall event Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

As the title, when I remove extension on Development mode, the Background Console disapear immediately. It makes hard to debug.

I want to write an event, call to the server if user remove my extension.

Details my code:

**manifest.json**

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"permissions": [ "management","storage","proxy", "*://*/*" ],
```

**bg.js**

```
chrome.management.onUninstalled.addListener(function (info) {
    console.log('Uninstall event caught!');
    // I write script here
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome.management.onUninstalled` is only fired when other extension is uninstalled.

1. You could listen to that in another extension.
2. You can use [`chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL) to do something in the server.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although it makes the browser open new tab, but it is really usage. Sorry for my bad English. @Haibara Ai

Comment: @HạTím, if that helps, please consider accepting it. Thanks.